How to Check if Stream of Objects that has a list with elements, has a element that is present in another list
I'm learning Java Streams and this a assignment at school. I've tried to understand how Streams work and searched the internet for examples and tutorials but haven't been able to figure this problem out.
So to the problem. A Stream of Pizza objects is given, pizzas have a name, a price and toppings which is a List of Strings. Also a String List of toppings are given. The goal is to return a Stream of pizzas that have any of the given toppings.
I know how to check if a single topping is in the pizzas toppings
Stream<Pizza> pizzasWithTopping =
        pizzas.filter(x -> x.toppings().contains(topping));

Now I'm stuck on how to go about checking if a given list of toppings contains a topping that is in a pizzas toppings.

What you would need is something akin to containsAny(...) (which a List does not have). One might try to use retainAll(...), but this modifies the original list, which might be immutable.

One option would be to use the Collections.disjoint method. disjoint() returns true if two collections have no common elements. Since you want to filter when two lists have common elements you can negate it to get the desired result
pizzas.filter(x -> !Collections.disjoint(x.getToppings(), toppings));


Okay I found examples that did help me to figure this out. Below is the code that works.
Stream<Pizza> pizzasWithAnyToppings = pizzas
.filter(x -> x.toppings()
.stream()
.anyMatch(toppings::contains));


